# Why does this code not produce a correct hash?

Tags: c, linux, encryption, hash, hashcode

I had to write a tiny decryption program in C to brute force a key from one file, here "resource.bin", and use that one to decrypt another file using DES-EDE, here "rom_dump.bin". The indication for the correct key is that the decrypted file content starts with a ten digit number terminated by `\0`. After that the decrypted content should be written to another file, here "decrypted.bin" and the file should be hashed with ECDSA (with the function `EVP_ecdsa()`). All of this is done on SUSE Linux. The files can be found here:

https://spideroak.com/browse/share/see/stack/StackOverflow/

Now, the decryption works just fine, but the hash value is not correct:

`a493af52c1a000fcace34de8b0a74a9cf9067ffc`

But even after days of searching, I just cannot find the problem. It's probably just something rediculess I'm overseeing but I'd be very glad if somebody could help me out here. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const unsigned long long bufferSize = 0x10000;

int checkOutput(unsigned char *output) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 6; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(output[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

void changeKey(unsigned char *key, unsigned char *fileContent, long keyLength,
long initVectorLength) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < keyLength + initVectorLength; i++) {
        key[i] = fileContent[i];
    }
}

void toHashFile(FILE *hashFile, unsigned char *hash, int hashLength) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < hashLength; i++) {
        fprintf(hashFile, "%02x", hash[i]);
    }

    fprintf(hashFile, "\n");
}

void toOutputFile(FILE *fileName, unsigned char *output,
int outputLength) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < outputLength; i++) {
        fprintf(fileName, "%c", output[i]);
    }

    fprintf(fileName, "\n");
}

void writeToFile(const unsigned char *fileName, unsigned char *content,
int contentLength,
void (*functionPointer)(FILE *, unsigned char *, int)) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "w");
    (*functionPointer)(file, content, contentLength);
    fclose(file);
}

void createHash(unsigned char *hash, unsigned char *output, int length,
int *hashLength) {
    EVP_MD_CTX hashContext;
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&hashContext);
    EVP_DigestInit(&hashContext, EVP_ecdsa());
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&hashContext, output, length);
    EVP_DigestFinal(&hashContext, hash, hashLength);
}

int main() {
    /* output stuff */
    unsigned char keyAndInitVector[24] = {0x00};
    unsigned char output[bufferSize];
    unsigned char outputFinal[bufferSize];
    int outputLength;

    /* determine key length and init vector */
    int initVectorLength = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_des_ede_ecb());
    int keyLength = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(EVP_des_ede_ecb());

    /* read resource files */
    unsigned char romFileContent[bufferSize];
    unsigned char resFileContent[bufferSize];
    int romLength = read(open("rom_dump.bin", O_RDONLY), romFileContent,
        bufferSize);
    int resLength = read(open("resource.bin", O_RDONLY), resFileContent,
        bufferSize);

    /* init context */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX cypherContext;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&cypherContext);

    int i = 0, j;
    int isDecrypted = 0;

    for (i; i < romLength - (keyLength + initVectorLength) &&
    !isDecrypted; i++) {
        changeKey(keyAndInitVector, romFileContent + i, keyLength,
            initVectorLength);

        EVP_DecryptInit(&cypherContext, EVP_des_ede_ecb(),
            keyAndInitVector, keyAndInitVector + keyLength);
        EVP_DecryptUpdate(&cypherContext, output, &outputLength,
            resFileContent, resLength);

        for (j = 0; j < resLength; j++) {
            if (checkOutput(output + j) == 1) {
                isDecrypted = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isDecrypted) {
        int postfixLength;
        EVP_DecryptFinal(&cypherContext, outputFinal,
            &postfixLength);

        writeToFile("decrypted.bin", output,
            outputLength + postfixLength, &toOutputFile);

        int hashLength = 0;
        unsigned char hash[bufferSize];
        createHash(hash, output, outputLength + postfixLength,
            &hashLength);
        writeToFile("hash.txt", hash, hashLength, &toHashFile);
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&cypherContext);
    return isDecrypted;
}
```

Comment: PS: Does anyone know a website where I could test the correctness of this very hash? I found sites for hashing with almost any known hash algorithm, except for this one I have to use.

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows or on a proper OS ? If it's Windows you'll need to add `O_BINARY` to the `open` calls.

Comment: This is being done on SUSE Linux. The file is compiled with `-lcrypto`. As I said, the decryption works, a hash value is also generated, but it's wrong.

Comment: OK - never mind - it was just a long shot. You might want to add a Linux tag to the question though.

Comment: I can provide you with the wrong hash (just updated), but as I did not find any website whatsoever to test for the right hash, I can not give you that, sorry. As for the files, I could paste them, but they contain many unprintable signs, so I'd rather link them. Hang on.

Comment: The files can be found here:
https://spideroak.com/browse/share/see/stack/StackOverflow/

Comment: ok. I must be missing something.  a hash is generated, I get the same one you do. And i get the same decryption (i better, I have the same hash, and can clearly see the C source file generated. But you claim it isn't "right"? How are you making that assessment? Compared to *what* ? (sorry if this seems an unrelated question, but if you can claim something is  NOT right there must be a method of proving what *is*). Are you compiling and running that source file, which uploads its firmware payload (clearly), and it fails a digest check on the *device* or some-such ?

Comment: Honestly, it wasn't me in the first place claiming the hash to be wrong. The person who gave the task to me claims it. I was sending the "decrypted.bin" and the "hash.txt" to that person, and only got "the hash is wrong" as response and he wouldn't say that if that wasn't the case. So it's my job to find the problem, but I'm just desperate as I don't see it. Is it a "\n", is it I'm using something else for hashing than lands in the file? I just don't know. I'm already blind looking at my source code.

Comment: Well, your decryption is certainly on par; too much would otherwise go wrong for it not to be. The final bits appear to be a german text translation. Maybe *that* final text is what the hash should be created from. Helluva job cracking this out, btw.

Comment: Well, what did you do to get the german text? Because I cannot see where you've got that from. The decrypted file appears to be a square-and-multipy function, but aside of that I don't see any readable text. But the task is very clear: "Determine the hash value of the decrypted data using the hash function ecdsa-with-SHA1 whose type the function `EVP_ecdsa()` returns."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `toOutputFile()` function, you add a `\n` to your file, but down in the `main()` you don't hash the file, but the `output`.

That means, your `decrypted.bin` has an additional `\n` which does not exist in your `output` which is why when hashing the file, the hash will be different from the one you created with that program.

Comment: Oh my god! How could I have overlooked that!?!?! Thank you very much for pointing that out! :D